# Select distinct rows where all values in a column are the same SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to find Distinct FKIDs where IsProcessed is True for the same FKIDs.
    e.g.

```
CID    FKID    DataField    IsProcessed

1      1       Test         1
2      1       Test         1
3      2       Test         0
4      2       Test         1
5      3       Test         0
6      3       Test         0
7      4       Test         1
8      5       Test         0
9      6       Test         1
10     6       Test         1
11     6       Test         1
```

I would like to get the following FKIDs Returned 1,4,6
because these are FKIDs where isprocessed is true for all instances.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks!

Comment: `select fkid from yourtable group by fkid having count(fkid) = sum(isprocessed)`

Comment: This logically made sense... except that I can't sum a bit field

Comment: so cast the bit to an int, or `sum(case when isprocessed=true then 1 else 0 end)` or whatever.

Comment: @ErikKlardie, use `CASE` or `CAST as INT`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `SUM() OVER` and `COUNT() OVER`

```
;WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT
        *,
        IsProcessedCount = SUM(CASE WHEN IsProcessed = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER(PARTITION BY FKID),
        cc = COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY FKID)
    FROM TEST
)
SELECT
    DISTINCT FKID
FROM CTE
WHERE IsProcessedCount = cc
```

---

Using `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`:

```
SELECT FKID
FROM Test
GROUP BY FKID
HAVING COUNT(FKID) = COUNT(CASE WHEN IsProcessed = 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)
```

Another way:

```
SELECT FKID
FROM Test
GROUP BY FKID
HAVING COUNT(FKID) = SUM(CAST(IsProcessed AS INT))
```

*Just replace `TEST` with your table.*

Comment: The Group by and Having query is an excellent suggestion and works great... Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT FKID
FROM TableName
GROUP BY FKID
HAVING (MIN(IsProcessed) = 1)
```

Or

```
SELECT FKID
FROM TableName
GROUP BY FKID
HAVING (MIN(CAST(IsProcessed AS INT)) = 1)
```

If IsProcessed is not of numeric type:

Answer (score 1):

Another way, using a correlated `not exists` predicate:

```
select fkid from TableName t
where IsProcessed = 1
  and not exists 
    (select 1 from TableName where IsProcessed = 0 and FKID = t.FKID)
group by fkid
```

or the same using `not in`:

```
select fkid from TableName t
where IsProcessed = 1
  and fkid not in 
    (select fkid from TableName where IsProcessed = 0 and FKID = t.FKID)
group by fkid
```

Comment: @wewesthemenace Most likely the `HAVING COUNT(FKID) = SUM(CAST(IsProcessed AS INT))` solution. I just added this for completeness.